# ¿Como relacionar varias tablas y obtener un resultado donde estan los campos de cada una? Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, modelorelacional

Estoy utilizando "Laravel 8", para entender la pregunta quiero darles el contexto:

Tengo 5 tablas para almacenar las caracteristicas de un Celular:

1. Marca: id, nomb_marca
2. Medida: id, medida
3. Modelo: id, nomb_modelo, marca_id
4. Caracteristicas: id, medida_id, modelo_id
5. RegistroCaracteristica: id, codigo, caract_id, activo

Como pueden ver tengo la tabla "Caracteristicas" donde se guardaran los "modelos, marcas y medidas" y otra tabla "RegistroCaracteristicas" donde les asigno el codigo a cada uno

En mi relacion "Eloquent" seria lo siguiente:

**Modelo Caracteristicas**

```
class RegCaracteristicas extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'reg_caracteristicas';

    public function caracteristicas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Caracteristica::class, 'caract_id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo RegCaracteristica**

```
class Caracteristicas extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'caracteristicas';

    public function reg_caract()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RegCaracteristica::class, 'caract_id');
    }
    public function Medida()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Medida::class, 'medida_id')
    }
    public function Modelo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Modelo::class, 'modelo_id')
    }
}
```

**Modelo, Modelo**

```
class Modelo extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'modelo';

    public function marca()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Marca::class, 'marca_id');
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero tener en el modelo "RegCaracteristica" es una funcion que me devuelva todas las "caracteristicas, modelos, medidas y marca completos", algo asi:

```
[
    {
        'id': '1',
        'codigo': 'A2020',
        'nomb_marca': 'Marca 1',
        'nomb_modelo': 'Modelo 2',
        'medida': 'Medida 3',
        'activo': '1'
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'codigo': 'A2021',
        'nomb_marca': 'Marca 2',
        'nomb_modelo': 'Modelo 2',
        'medida': 'Medida 2',
        'activo': '0'
    }
]
```

Se como hacerlo, pero usando "Query Builder", por ejemplo, el uso de "JOINS" donde relacionaria todas las tablas y con un "select" obtendria eso mismo, de la siguiente forma:

**EDIT 01:** Creamos el scope CaractFull, en ella hacemos los joins respectivos y seleccionamos lo que queremos, despues en el controlador solo hacemos `RegCaracteristica::caractFull()->get()` y listo, ya obtengo lo que "querria"

```
public function scopeCaractFull($query)
{
    return $query
        ->join('caracteristicas', 'caracteristicas.id', '=', 'reg_caracteristica.caract_id')
        ->join('medida', 'medida.id', '=', 'caracteristicas.medida_id')
        ->join('modelo', 'modelo.id', '=', 'caracteristicas.modelo_id')
        ->join('marca', 'marca.id', '=', 'modelo.marca_id')
        ->select('reg_caracteristica.id', 'codigo', 'nomb_marca', 'nomb_modelo', 'medida', 'activo');
}
```

Pero quiero hacerlo en "Eloquent" y no encuentro la forma

Gracias a todos!

Comment: ¿Por qué medidas lo consideras como una tabla por separado?

Comment: Nop, mencioné medidas

Comment: @BetaM porque mas adelante agregare el campo "diferencia", para indicar la diferencia de cada medida, por ejemplo: X medida tiene esta diferencia con Y medida, etc. Por lo que si lo hago junto, tendria que escribir siempre la misma diferencia a cada medida

Comment: @BetaM pero existira alguna forma de hacerlo? Lei la documentacion pero solo encuentro relaciones morph

Comment: Me causó curiosidad, me haré un espacio para que con lo que nos expones poder formular una respuesta, aunque ayudaría mucho si añades lo que hayas intentado aunque no funcione

Comment: @BetaM listo, aunque investigando mas me di cuenta que se puede usar `scopes` para obtenerlo del modelo y asi lo hice

Comment: si esa es la solución a tu problema entonces no va en tu pregunta sino en la zona de respuestas, por favor edita y corrije

Comment: @BetaM aunque pensandolo mejor creo que se deberian hacer varios scopes y obtener un select de cada relacion para despues juntarlos y obtener lo que quiero

Comment: Hubiera sido mas simple utilizando load() o with()

Comment: @BetaM no es la solucion, por eso puse que lo puedo hacer por "Joins"pero yo quiero por "Eloquent"

Comment: @Dohko19 no conosco `load`, me darias un significado simple para que sirve?

Comment: @bemoba1437 es una buena practica y mas recomendable pasarse a ver toda la documentacion de laravel ya que todos los benefecios que provee se encuentran alli, muchas veces en videos y tutoriales gratis no explican esto: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-multiple-relationships

Comment: los join en eloquent funcionan igual que en el QB, no veo la necesidad de pasarlo a la otra forma, lo que puedes hacer es no usar el scope y hacer la consulta directa al modelo, la verdad no entiendo para que quieres pasar a eloquent? en que te esta fallando

Comment: @NicolasAldana utilizo scope porque dicho dato lo uso en varios controladores, en realidad no es lo que falla sino la logica en si, estoy relacionando todas las tablas con joins cuando tengo modelos para eso y siento que no esta bien, o lo esta?